# how to pass a variable via exec*

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec

I want to pass a int variable to another process after exec*

here is my code:

```
typedef union{
    int i;
    char c[4];
}t_t;

/* parent */
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    t_t tv;

    tv.i = 12345;

    if(fork() == 0)
        execlp("./test", tv.c, "abcd", (char *)0);
    return 0;
}

/* child */
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    t_t tv;

    memcpy(tv.c, av[0], sizeof(int));

    printf("child: ac=%d, av0: %d, av1: %s\n", ac, tv.i, av[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**here is output:

child: ac=2, av0: 1627402297, av1: abcd**

I also try like this:

```
int i;
execlp("./test", (char *)i, "abcd", (char *)0);
```

the argv[0] in the child is unexpected always.

I wonder why it can't work like I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union isn't converting the number to its string representation as you seem to expect.  What it's actually doing is allowing access to the individual bytes that make up the `int`, which is not a string.  Passing a character array that is not a string to a function expecting a string invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What you want instead is to use `snprintf` to convert the integer to a string and pass that string to `execlp`.  Then in the child process, use `atoi` to convert the string back to an integer.

```
/* parent */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[50];
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d", 12345);

    if(fork() == 0)
        execlp("./test", str, "abcd", (char *)0);
    return 0;
}

/* child */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = atoi(argv[0]);

    printf("child: argc=%d, argv0: %d, argv1: %s\n", argc, i, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx, it work! but I have a question still, which is the union use the same memory with each member. so, of course, the    tv.i is same as the    tv.a, and, it can passing to exec* like char *. and I right?

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL The `i` and `c` fields in the union do occupy the same memory, but `c` isn't what `i` looks like as a string.  Assuming little-endian byte ordering, 12345 (0x3039 in hex) is represented by the bytes 0x39 0x30 0x0 0x0, which is what `c` will subsequently contain.  This does end up being a null terminated string, and assuming ASCII encoding the resulting string is actually "90".